# Tooltips for custom function signatures in TextMate

Tags: php, textmate, web-development, ide

I'm using TextMate, and there is a good short key to see "documentation for function call (tooltip)". But it works only for PHP-internal functions.

It would be good to have this functionality for user-defined functions. This information could be taken from the phpdoc block.

I'm already using ctags to jump from function to function, but maybe there is a way to integrate tag files with showing function signature (definition)?

Comment: Isn't there a "Documentation for Function Call (tool tip)" in the PHP bundle?

Comment: Yes but it works only for internal function. What about my own functions (class methods etc .. ) ?

Comment: No, I don't think there is such a feature. Maybe you can modify the existing one?

Comment: this is what about my question :) is there anyone who has ready solution. Because this tooltip for custom function could be very helpfull.